# "Error converting" numeric input to correct TSQL type (possible Bug)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, t-sql

As of now I am encountering this kind of bug

> Error converting data type float to decimal.

or

> Error converting data type Numeric to decimal

This is my code

```
using (SqlConnection reportsConn = new SqlConnection(sqlConnWriter))
{
            reportsConn.Open();
            SqlCommand AddReconItem = new SqlCommand();
            AddReconItem.Connection = reportsConn;
            AddReconItem.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            AddReconItem.CommandText = "Updater.usp_AddReconcileItems";
           // AddReconItem.Parameters.Add("@varible",SqlDbType.Decimal
            AddReconItem.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ITEMWEIGHT", Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(WeightTextBox.Text+".00"), 2));
            AddReconItem.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ITEMPRINCIPALAMT", Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(PrincipalTexAmTextBox.Text + ".00"), 2));
            AddReconItem.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FORLOANMONTH", Convert.ToDateTime(YearDropDownList.SelectedValue + "/" + MonthDropDownList.SelectedValue));
            AddReconItem.Parameters.AddWithValue("@STORAGEGROUPID", StorageNameDropDownList.SelectedValue);
            AddReconItem.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BRANCHCODE",BranchCodeTextBox.Text);
            AddReconItem.Parameters.AddWithValue("RECONID", ReconTypeDropDownList.SelectedValue);
            AddReconItem.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PAWNTIX",PwnTicketTextBox.Text);
            AddReconItem.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CREATEDBY", Session["UserID"].ToString());
            AddReconItem.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

When I input, `123` for `principalamt` and `itemweight` it accepts the answer and treats it as a decimal, but when I input `1234` for `itemweight` and still `123` for `Principalamt` it shows that error, if I remove the conversion and change it to `Convert.ToDecimal` it shows `Error converting data type Numeric to decimal` if I use it as text it shows `Error converting data type varchar to decimal`

Is this a bug or something? I can't seem to find a way I tried many options but none of them have been working

My database columns are below:

I really hope you can help me understand this phenomenon

**EDIT**
This is the first time I saw a program accepting 123 as a valid input while 1234 is not, my database `Decimal (38,6)` is very large enough to accommodate this input that's why I'm looking for the answer or known bugs that can solve this problem, thank you.

Comment: Can you isolate the problem to *just*, say, the money type? (Be careful with the term "bug" or "bugs" in titles or tags - these should be reserved for rare cases of asserting an issue with a well-established program/library :)

Comment: @user2246674 there are no problems with the money type im suspecting the problem in the Decimal type.

Comment: @user2246674 isn't this a rare case? i never seen a flow of inoutting 123 as it accepts it while 1234 is not an accepted input?

Comment: This post does not contain enough evidence or sufficient test-case to assert the hypothesis that there is a bug in the .NET framework or core libraries. I'm not saying that it is not the case, but merely that this is insufficient exploration to start down the "bug" (in not-my-code) route :)

Comment: WHERE IS THE CODE? Where is the stored procedure? You are passing the parameters to a stored procedure, not storing them directoy to the table. If there is any kind of conversion problem you need to check the stored procedure first. I bet you'll find @ItemwWeight defined somewhat different from decimal(38,6), or there is some weird conversion in the stored procedure code itself. Eg. where did thath `varchar` come from? Is @ItemWeight defined as a varchar or are you storing it to a varchar variable before storing it to the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest using Decimal.TryParse instead of Convert for your principalamt value and then maybe debugging and inspecting how the value gets converted to a valid Decimal for your Money column. For example something like;

```
bool valid;
var dbl = Convert.ToDouble("1234.00");
valid = Double.TryParse("1234.00", out dbl);

var dcml = Convert.ToDecimal("1234.00");
valid = Decimal.TryParse("1234.00", out dcml);
```

I'm not sure if you should be using Double as a data type when trying to store the resultant value in a Decimal field. [Double](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/678hzkk9.aspx) represents floating type numbers and I think you should be using the Decimal data type for your Money column as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1165788/685760).

For ItemWeight, with a data type of decimal(38,6), you'll end up with 6 decimal places regardless of your rounding I think. Try the following in SQL Server and make sure the parameter type for @ITEMPRINCIPALAMT is DECIMAL as well (similar to my example below).

```
DECLARE @Var decimal(38,6) = 1234.00

DECLARE @Tbl AS TABLE
(
   Test decimal(38,6)
)

INSERT INTO @Tbl (Test) Values (@Var)

SELECT * FROM @Tbl
```